# Java generic is not applicable for the arguments List<Object>

Tags: java, java-8

I am playing with generics in Java. But I do have currently problem. In short this code should be converting one object of one list and than putting it in another list. (From T to U)

My code looks like that

```
public class ListConvertor<T, U> {

    private final Convertor<T, ? extends U> convertor;

    public ListConvertor( Convertor<T, ? extends U> convertor ) {
        this.convertor = convertor;
    }

    public void convertList( List<T> from, List<U> to ) {
        if ( from == null )
            return;

        for ( T ch : from ) {
            to.add( convertor.convert( ch ) );
        }
    }
}

public interface Convertor<T, V> {

    V convert( T dataModelObject ) throws JEDXException;

}
```

It is working correctly for something like this:

```
new ListConvertor<>(new IntListConvertor()).convertList(in.getIntLists(), out.getIntLists());
```

When using this code like above everything is working correctly, because `int` and `out` `getIntList` methods are returning `List<IntList>` and `List<IntListType>`

```
public final class IntListConvertor implements Convertor<IntList, IntListType>
```

But I would like to use it aswell with `List<Object>` on out parameter. So it would looks like that:

```
List<Object> outObjectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
new ListConvertor<>(new IntListConvertor()).convertList(in.getIntLists(), outObjectList );
```

But when using that like this I am getting error:

```
The method convertList(List<IntCharacteristic>, List<IntCharacteristicType>) in the type ListConvertor<IntCharacteristic,IntCharacteristicType> is not applicable for the arguments (List<IntCharacteristic>, List<Object>)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the method signature from

```java
public void convertList(List<T> from, List<U> to)
```

to

```java
public void convertList(List<T> from, List<? super U> to)
```

If `U` is `Integer` you can now accept the following to lists

- `List<Integer>`
- `List<Number>`
- `List<Object>`

**Further tipps**

You should also change `List<T> from` to `List<? extends T> from`. This way if T is `Number` you can pass

- `List<Number>`
- `List<Integer>`
- `List<Double>`
- ...